# Is it possible to write short if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, rest-assured

Here is my if statements. I just want to write shorter. Because i think these are uneffective. By the way each if statements are independent.

```
String actual_createdDate = "^\\d{13}$";
String actual_modifiedDate = "^\\d{13}$";
...

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    if (js.getBoolean("[" + i + "].createdDate")) {
        String a = js.get("[" + i + "].createdDate").toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(a.matches(actual_createdDate));
    }
    if (js.getBoolean("[" + i + "].lastModifiedDate")) {
        String b = js.get("[" + i + "].lastModifiedDate").toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(b.matches(actual_modifiedDate));
    }
    if (js.getBoolean("[" + i + "].uuid")) {
        String c = js.get("[" + i + "].uuid").toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(c.matches(actual_uuid));
    }
    if (js.get("[" + i + "].coverPhoto") != null) {
        String d = response1.jsonPath().get("[" + i + "].coverPhoto.tempDownloadURL").toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(d.matches(actual_temp_url));
        System.out.println(js.get("[" + i + "].coverPhoto.tempDownloadURL").toString() + " is equalent to : " + actual_temp_url);
    }
    if (js.get("[" + i + "].coverPhoto.metadata['Thumbnail-Large']") != null) {
        String e = response1.jsonPath().get("[" + i + "].coverPhoto.metadata['Thumbnail-Large']").toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(e.matches(actual_metaData_url));
        System.out.println(js.get("[" + i + "].coverPhoto.metadata['Thumbnail-Large']").toString() + " is equalent to : " + actual_metaData_url);
    }

}
```

Comment: Regardless of the ifs `js.getBoolean("[" + i + "].createdDate")` looks terrible.

Comment: besides using just one generic String instead of defining 5 different ones, i don't see clearly where you can shorten this...

Comment: There's no reason to repeatedly build `"[" + i + "]"` and repeatedly build the path name; build each thing only once.

Comment: @luk2302 Actually my response has repetitive data's. I just want to check all data's values. And i use regex for test data. For example if the coverPhoto doesnt exist in the ressponse i dont want get error so thats why used **js.getBoolean("[" + i + "].createdDate")** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to introduce you to the first-class unit of code reuse known amongst circles of weirdos as a "*function*" ;)

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    assertEqual(js, i, "createdDate", actual_createdDate);
    assertEqual(js, i, "lastModifiedDate", actual_modifiedDate);
    assertEqual(js, i, "uuid", actual_uuid);
    assertEqual(js, i, "coverPhoto", actual_temp_url);
    assertEqual(js, i, "coverPhoto.metadata['Thumbnail-Large']", actual_metaData_url);
}
    
private void assertEqual(JS js /*idk the type*/, int i, String fieldName, String expectedValue) {
    String property = "[" + i + "]." + fieldName;
    if (js.getBoolean(property)) {
        String value = js.get(property).toString();
        Assert.assertTrue(value.matches(expectedValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: (Noting that this won't work as-is because they're not all booleans.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh, I didn't have the ability to compile it, so I made some guesses. I didn't notice that some cases used `get(...) != null` and some used `getBoolean`. I assumed `getBoolean` was checking for presence of the property, since `lastModifiedDate` is presumably not a boolean. It's a date. If it is a boolean, then yikes...